# Angular отмена отправки запроса

Tags: javascript, http, события, angular

У меня есть rest приложения, с ангуляра отправляю запросы на сервер для поиска данных. Данные отправляются каждые полторы секунды при вводе новых значений (аля живой поиск). Как я могу реализовать отмену отправки запроса, если он еще не пришёл? Т.е. я отправляю первый запрос и за ним сразу же второй, если ответа на первый еще нет надо чтобы сразу отображался ответ второго, без отображения первого. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом я могу это реализовать.

Комонент ангуляр:

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'input')
        .pipe(
            filter(Boolean),
            debounceTime(150),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            tap((text) => {
                this.searchNotes();
            })
        )
        .subscribe();
}
searchNotes() {
    this.page = 0;
    this.getNotes();
}
    getNotes() {
    this.getCountNotes();
    this.isLoaded = false;
    this.noteService.getNotes(this.page, this.sortBy, this.searchNoteValue)
        .subscribe((notes: Note[]) => {
            this.userNotes = notes;
            this.isLoaded = true;
        }, error => {
            if (error.status === 403) {
                this.logOut();
            }
        });
}
```

notesService:

```
    getNotes(page: number, sortBy: string, searchValue: string) {
    return this.http.get(`/notes?page=${page}&sortBy=${sortBy}&searchValue=${searchValue}`);
}
```

Comment: Вы не сможете реализовать остановку бакенда с фронта. Это невозможно :)

Comment: Я не хочу останавливать бэк, пускай он там перегрузиться хоть. Я на фронте хочу отоброжать только один последний результат, а не все вызванные

Comment: В таком случае нужен код от вас. Как у вас реализован данный функционал, т.к. есть несколько подходов к решению данного вопроса.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko добавил, смотрите

Answer (score -2):

### это не ответ на вопрос

это небольшое **IMHO** по работе с формами по типу проверки орфографии

> Я не хочу останавливать бэк, пускай он там перегрузиться хоть. Я на фронте хочу отоброжать только один последний результат, а не все вызванные – джанго123

- `throttle`

  - http://underscorejs.ru/#throttle
  - https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle
    там есть кнопка `source` и `npm package`
- `debounce`

  - http://underscorejs.ru/#debounce
  - https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce
    там есть кнопка `source` и `npm package`

> See [David Corbacho's article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) for details over the differences between [*.debounce*](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) and [.throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce).